# Saving music state

Tags: android, service, state, media

I am having an issue with the music playback of my app. I set up the media player within a Service class which plays music throughout the application fine. However, the issue I'm having is when changing screens from the Options page to the Home page again.

In the option class, I have a single `ToggleButton` which turns the music on and off when it's clicked, and I have used a boolean to determine whether the `ToggleButton` is auto on and off, depending on whether the music is playing.

However, when the user clicks the back button or the save button (which both send them back to the home page) the music starts playing again, even if it's checked as "off".

Does anyone have a suggestion for me?

**Service Class:**

```
public class MyMusicService extends Service {
MediaPlayer mp;


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);


    mp.start();
    mp.setLooping(true);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    if(mp!=null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();

    }
    mp=null;
}

}
```

**Options Class:**

```
public class OptionsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
            Intent i = new Intent(OptionsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(String serviceCanonicalClassName) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceCanonicalClassName.equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    Intent i; // Handles MyMusicService.java

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.options);



        final TextView tSound = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        final Button saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.optSaveBtn);
        final Button tblBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tableBtn);

        i=new Intent(this, MyMusicService.class);

        final ToggleButton soundOption = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.soundPref);


        boolean musicPlays = isMyServiceRunning(MyMusicService.class.getCanonicalName());


        soundOption.setChecked(musicPlays); 


        if(musicPlays==true){

            tSound.setText("On");
        }

        if(musicPlays==false) { 

            tSound.setText("Off");
        }


        soundOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {   

                // Perform action on clicks to control sound being on and off.   
                if(soundOption.isChecked()) {  

                    Toast.makeText(OptionsActivity.this, "Music on.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    startService(i);
                    Intent i = new Intent(OptionsActivity.this, OptionsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                } 

                else {  

                    if(stopService(i)==true){

                        soundOption.setChecked(false);
                        stopService(i);
                        Toast.makeText(OptionsActivity.this, "Music off.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(OptionsActivity.this, OptionsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }  
                }
            }

        });



        tblBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent tblView = new Intent(OptionsActivity.this, SQLView.class);
                startActivity(tblView);

            }
        });



        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent homePage = new Intent(OptionsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                switch (v.getId()){ 

                case R.id.optSaveBtn: //Determine what will happen when the user presses the "Submit button".
                    boolean optionsWork = true;
                    try{

                        String sound = tSound.getText().toString();

                        optionsDB entry = new optionsDB(OptionsActivity.this); //Creating a new instance of MasterMind game
                        entry.open();
                        entry.createOptionEntry(sound); //Passing both strings
                        entry.close();

                    }catch (Exception e){ //Creating an error message if for some reason the app cannot transfer data to the Database.

                        Toast.makeText(OptionsActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    finally { //Creating an AlertDialog box when the user presses the Submit button.

                        if (optionsWork){

                            Toast.makeText(OptionsActivity.this, "Settings Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }

                    break;

                }

                startActivity(homePage);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**And finally, the home class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    

Intent i;

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(String serviceCanonicalClassName) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceCanonicalClassName.equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


public void checkSound(){

boolean musicPlays = isMyServiceRunning(MyMusicService.class.getCanonicalName());

    if(musicPlays==true){

        //Do nothing
    }
    else {

        stopService(i);

    }

}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //setting the layout

    //Start Networking
    //Intent net = new Intent(this, Networking.class);
    //startService(net);

    //Auto starts playing music on app launch.
    i = new Intent(this,MyMusicService.class);
    startService(i);
    checkSound();


    final ImageView findGame = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnFindGame);
    final ImageView profile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnProfile);
    final ImageView instructions = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnInstructions);
    final ImageView options = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnOptions);

    findGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrawActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WaitingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    instructions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InstructionsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OptionsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

//On app close, music stops playing. 
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (this.isFinishing()){
        super.onDestroy();
        stopService(i);
        //finish();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're creating the home screen, you are also starting the service again.  In your 'onStartCommand' of the service you are starting the media player.  That means that every time you go to the homepage, the media player will start playing again.

I would recommend not putting `mp.start();` in the 'onStartCommand' but instead in its own function.  Then after you call `startService(i);` you can bind to the the service using `bindService()` then call a function such as play() on the service handle you have.

Of course if you are pausing the song instead of stopping you will need to save the position of the songs and then use `seekTo()` to move the song to the proper position when you restart the service.

I'd recommend reading through the Android service page [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your comment.

I don't suppose you could show me an example of this? I've been trying for a bit and I'm running into a few problems. Either it not playing or errors in the code.

Answer (score 0):

i think u have to place  some check on start service in your home class on create method,

```
    check if(your service is running)
       {
          if(mp is playing)
             {
                //do nothing
             }
       }
    else
       {
         startservice();
       }
```